# SonnarQube's issue: change code to not construct the URL from user-controlled data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube

I facing a SonarQube bug and am not able to figure out whats the issue. SonnarQube's issue is, change this code to not construct the URL from user-controlled data.

```
@Value("${...}")
String apiKey;

@Value("${...}")
String apiUrl;

public Response apiResponse(String location) {

   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.add("x-apikey", apiKey);

   HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

   String url = apiUrl + location; // SonarQube issue: tainted value is propagated

   Response response = null;

   try {

      ResponseEntity<Response> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Response.class); // SonarQube issue: Tainted value is used to perform a security- sensitive operation.

      response = responseEntity.getBody();

   } catch(Exception){

       // doesn't throw anything

   }

   return response;

}

@Cacheable(...)
Response cacheResponse(String location, String tokenKey) {

  return apiResponse(location); // SonarQube issue: tainted value is propagated
}
```

This fixed the issue, but why is that so? and how can I apply this in the above code?

```
 String url = apiUrl + location; // SonarQube issue: tainted
```

Instead, I just tried hardcoding the value of location and fixed the issue.

```
String url = apiUrl + "location";
```

So weird...

Comment: As I understand from sonarqube issue don't take url parameter from user's data that is given by user input.

Comment: Just imagine that user wants to send request anywhere he/she wants. It is not appropriate to change url with user input.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez but I need to get information based on location. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I added validation for the Location variable and this solved the issue

```
if(!location.matches(...)) {
   throw error.....
}

String url = apiUrl + location;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using input from the client/user (namly in the variable location) to construct an URL. So if the client/user supplies an malicious value to location he could form an invalid URL.

In the second example `String url = apiUrl + "location";` you are not using user input, as "location" is a hard coded String.

I don't know what you try to achieve with the code. But maybe it's better to hold a list of possible URLs and the user supplies and enum value that maps to an URL.

Comment: I need to get information based on location. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You should check if the provided value is valid (for example an regex to check for allowed characters). And you should at least escape the value you add to an url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters

Answer (score 0):

What SonarQube is trying to tell you is that you are exposing your logic to input from the clients. A better solution would be to refactor your code to not depend on a specific header from the client to perform some action. Its hard to suggest sample code without seeing a little more of the codebase.

Comment: I just updated my observation

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "https://someurl/%s";
url = String.format(url,location);
sendRequest(url);
```

Maybe this approach won't give error.

Comment: what's the use of adding "/%s"?

Comment: replacement string where you will replace location variable

Comment: I just added a location validation to throw an error if it fails and that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this Azure Storage Account Key is not disclosed. This message showing in sonarqube in the project. how to solve this.

Comment: You aren't answering the question. When you post an answer, it **must** answer the question. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] in order to understand how SO works. If you have a question, then post a question.